# Connecting to MySql using port 3307

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to connect to MySql database remotely using the following script on port 3307

```
   $username="user";
   $password="pass";
   $database="db"; 
   mysql_connect('ccline.dyndns.info:3307',$username,$password);

   @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
```

but unable to connect. I was using this same script on a db using 3306. What am I missing??

Comment: What do you get if you echo `mysql_error()`?

Comment: 1) You shouldn't be using the `mysql_*` functions. 2) I think it would easier to connect with the PDO functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: Is ccline.dyndns.info a real address? Use [port-scan](http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/) here to scan if the port is accessible.

Comment: everything is open, I am currently running one page that is connecting using pure PHP with a .xml config template. I am wanting to simplify my scripts. ccronline.dyndns.info is my actual host link.

Comment: this page http://bangalorechristianradio.com/PHP/web/play_info.php is being populated from the same database

Answer (score 1):

There a three things you need to connect to a remote database:

- port 3306 open on the firewalls. Firewalls in server and client must open port 3306!
- in my.cnf bind-address = 0.0.0.0 to let mysql bind to all interfaces
- sufficient privileges in the database to allow remote connections

Virtual all hosting companies close port 3306 on the firewall, and do not allow direct remote access. And even if they do, you won't get privileges to connect to a database.

Only if the remote database is in your LAN, or you are using a VPS with root access you can configure things to make a remote connection.

Answer (score 1):

First: You miss to use the mysqli_* functions instead of the mysql_* function [For more informations take a look here](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

To your question: I bet, on your mysql_server **ccline.dyndns.info** the port 3306 / 3307 is not open ... or the server is configurated not to listen on request wich are not equal **localhost**

So if you use the php-script on the same machine as the mysql server, connect by **localhost:3307** .....

Comment: everything is open, I am currently running one page that is connecting using pure PHP with a .xml config template. I am wanting to simplify my scripts. ccronline.dyndns.info is my actual host link. 
 
this page bangalorechristianradio.com/PHP/web/play_info.php is being populated from the same database

Comment: He didn't ask for instructions on how to use "mysqli_*" functions. Maybe he is bound to mysql_oldschool for some reasons (legacy system)